# In Mice and mystics, Should party items be place in paw to use them?

Tags: mice-and-mystics

I just finished first chapter in mice and mystics. I had a quick clarification to make. 
To be able to use the party item, is it okay to have that in the pack? Or are those cards not counted as item cards at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those cards aren't counted against your pack limit at all.  You simply place the corresponding token in the party items area (the middle of the clock).  Page 18 states

> Party items are items that can be used freely by any mouse in the
>   party. When a mouse receives a party item, place the card near the
>   story control board and place any marker or token that might be
>   associated with that item in the party stash area of the story control
>   board.